# SQL ce data paging possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, data-paging

Is there a way to implement data paging with sql ce? It would be for windows mobile app.

Currently using the sql compact edition 3.5. Also using the Microsoft Sync Framework ADO.net v1.0 for device.

Comment: Which version of SQL Compact are you planning to use? Paging support is coming in SQL Compact 4.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the rows on each page manually.